# How to pass a dynamic prop to a component through router in Vue JS 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-props

I need to pass a prop to a component that I access through vue router:

**router.ts**

```
    {
      path: '/document/create',
      name: 'createdocument',
      component: CreateDocument,
      props: { object: {} }
    },
```

Basically, I access the component CreateDocument from the **FolderDetailView.vue**

```
   ...
           <div v-if="userModel.role !== 'Viewer'">
              <IconButton float="right" link="createdocument" :params="{ object: folder }">
                <template #svgicon>
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-white" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 4v16m8-8H4" />
                  </svg>
                </template>
              </IconButton>
            </div>
   ...
```

and I would like to pass the folder object as a prop that can be used in CreateDocument, to initialise the value of a form field.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode